# access VPN machine macosx same subnet

Tags: macos, vpn, lan, remote-access, subnet

I would like to access the office machine, which has a fixed IP, and is available only in its local LAN.

Let say 192.168.1.100.

I have a VPN with username/password connection and I am trying to access the office machine from another location, i.e., another LAN, which has the same subnet: 192.168.1.50.

I am using MacOSX 10.8.

I have checked the "send all trafic over VPN connection, but I think it looks like it doesn't care and is searching in Local.

I do not have admin privileges and can't request to make changes to the network settings in both LANs.

Is there any way to connect to the desired remote machine?

Edit:
The recomandation it is:
[image: screenshot]
probably it will work, I can't test now. I have read also it is a command line: route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you might try (while keeping the 'send everything via VPN' checkbox checked) is dragging the VPN connection to the top of the list in the Network pane of System Preferences. OSX prioritizes connections based on that list.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible, given your constraints.

Your home network is probably also 192.168.1.x.  *If* you could change it to something else, for instance 192.168.5.x, you'd be good-to-go.

Comment: "I do not have admin privileges and can't request to make changes to the network settings in both LANs."

Comment: You only need to change one end of the connection, either end.

Comment: I told above I can't make network changes twice. Should I down vote?

Comment: I've edited my answer to align more closely with your constraints.